# Is there an equivalent to window.clipboardData in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

In our application, we have a custom paste function that calls window.clipboardData.getData("Text") to get the current clipboard data. It then performs some functions on this data. In Edge, window.clipboardData is undefined. It does seem that getData works when used within the "paste" event though such as the following.

```
document.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    var test = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
});
```

I potentially can design a workaround that will involve this overriding of the paste event, but it would be non-ideal. A solution that can be called outside of an event would be preferable.

As an aside, I read that Edge did not support the clipboard API at one point, but my understanding is that this is fixed, so please find something specifically sustantiating the current functionality (e.clipboardData working but no equivalent to window.clipboardData existing if that is your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edge, like all modern browsers uses the official [ClipboardEvent::clipboardData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData):

```js
inp.onpaste = evt =>
  console.log(evt.clipboardData.getData('text'));
```

```html
<input id="inp">
```

Go with it. The deprecated and non-standard *window::clipboardData* should only be used as a mean of legacy support, for older versions of IE.

As to what you wish to do, (paste without user interaction), that goes against [the specs recommendations for privacy](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#privacy-events). You won't be able to do from web-content. You'll need to run your script from an high-privilege script, like an extension.

> • Implementations must not let scripts create synthetic clipboard events to get access to real clipboard data (unless the user has configured it to do so).

Comment: The OP wants to paste without user interaction.

Comment: @PoulBak they can't. MS fixed this issue in Edge.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, but OP is probably not.

Comment: From a privacy perspective I'm glad too. From a "getting my intranet system browser compatible" perspective, not so much. I needed support for both pasting into a single field and having tab-delimited data pasting replace multiple fields/lines in a grid. We had a button for the second type of paste in the past, but now I have a workaround overriding the paste event. I'll post an answer with my code.

Comment: @BrandonBarkley if it's for your intranet can't you simply set up an extension on all the posts? Extensions can access clipboard data with no restriction (when granted the *clipboardRead* permission). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Reading_from_the_clipboard

Comment: @Kaiido It is definitely a solution, but probably more overhead than I need when I could trap and data mine a standard paste instead to determine which function needs to be performed. I will keep that in mind for more complex implementations though!

Answer (score 1):

As Kaiido noted, it is not possible to get at the pasted content outside of the paste event in Edge (and Chrome for that matter).

Users previously used a custom right-click menu to access "Paste From Excel" functionality to replace content in an editable grid with tab-delimited content from the clipboard. If window.clipboardData is undefined the user received a message saying that you must use the standard CTRL+V paste in this browser.

I then added the listener below which essentially determined if the content was tab-delimited and treated it as a "Paste from Excel" whereas it treated other data layouts as a standard "Paste". This was sufficient for my deployment, but for others, it may be worthwhile to launch a confirm window to verify intention.

```
document.getElementById(myGridID).addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    var clipboardContent = window.clipboardData ? window.clipboardData.getData("Text") : (e.clipboardData ? e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") : "");
    if(clipboardContent != null && clipboardContent.indexOf('\t') >= 0)
    {
        MyExcelPasteFunction(myGridID, clipboardContent);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```